# Hibernate Cache Always Misses

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using Hibernate with Spring framework, and trying to cache a query which is written through the CriteriaAPI. I've enabled the query cache and the 2nd Level cache. I've also set the setCacheable to true in that particular query. The problem is that hibernate session statistics show that it hits the database everything for the same query I'm running multiple times.

Here's the function with the criteria query

```
@Override
public Collection<Article> findLatestArticle(int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession()
    .createCriteria(Article.class)
    .setCacheable(true)
    .setCacheRegion(CACHE_REGION)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("isVisible", 1))
    //.createCriteria("Count")
    //.add(Restrictions.eq("Count", count))
    .setFirstResult(0)
    .setMaxResults(count);

    return criteria.list();
}
```

here's the caller function

```
@Test
public void t1(){
    List<Article> articleList = (List<Article>) articleDao.findLatestArticle(1);

    //Article a = articleDao.findById(articlePk);

    for(int i=0; i<19; i++)
        articleDao.findLatestArticle(1);

    Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getSessionFactory().getStatistics();

    //System.out.println("2nd Lvl Stats: " + stats.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(CACHE_REGION));
    stats.logSummary();

    System.out.println("Empty: " + articleList.isEmpty());

    assertTrue(!articleList.isEmpty());
    //assertNotNull(a);
}
```

spring-hibernate-context file

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.Ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

ehcache portion of this class

```
<cache name="com.contento3.cms.article.model.Article"
maxElementsInMemory="10000"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="300"
timeToLiveSeconds="60"
overflowToDisk="true"/>
```

Log Excerpts:

```
    2012-11-14 21:05:03,020 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
2012-11-14 21:05:03,020 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: enabled
    2012-11-14 21:05:03,969 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache - starting query cache at region: com.contento3.cms.article.model.Article
2012-11-14 21:05:03,998 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 10ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,010 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 1ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,019 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 8ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,022 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,024 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,026 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,033 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 7ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,035 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,038 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,041 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,050 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 3ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,059 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 9ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,062 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 3ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,067 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 4ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,074 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 5ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,077 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,079 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 1ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,081 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 1ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,083 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,085 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.Statistics - HQL: from Article as a, time: 2ms, rows: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,085 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - Logging statistics....
2012-11-14 21:05:04,085 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - start time: 1352909103053
2012-11-14 21:05:04,085 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - sessions opened: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,085 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - sessions closed: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - transactions: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - successful transactions: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - optimistic lock failures: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - flushes: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - connections obtained: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - statements prepared: 21
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - statements closed: 21
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - second level cache puts: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - second level cache hits: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - second level cache misses: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - entities loaded: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - entities updated: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - entities inserted: 1
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - entities deleted: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,086 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - entities fetched (minimize this): 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - collections loaded: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - collections updated: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - collections removed: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - collections recreated: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - collections fetched (minimize this): 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - queries executed to database: 20
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - query cache puts: 20
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - query cache hits: 0
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - query cache misses: 20
2012-11-14 21:05:04,087 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.stat.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl - max query time: 10ms
```

I'm fairly new to Spring and Hibernate. I've read at least a dozen articles regarding this issue and did everything that I could. Also, I wrote a similar query using createQuery method, the result was the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Article object marked with @Cache annotation??

Comment: @chrislhardin: Yes, I've added them like this.

`@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class Article implements Serializable  { .... `

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling the Annotations for this 
@Cacheable
@cache with caching strategies